# Spring Boot ConfigurationProperties - Base Class is not mapped

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to setup a spring-boot configuration that uses different properties which have the same base class. The problem is that the base type is always null.

I am doing this because I want have different configuration elements that have a set of required properties and also have some additional properties .

For context: The configuration file looks as follows and is saved as JSON:

```
{
  // some other properties
  "layout": {
    "test": 1,
    "element": {
      "@type": "traffic",
      "id": "id-1",
      "district": "district"
    }
  }
```

For this **layout** property I use the following class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "layout")
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LayoutProperties {
    /* This is always correct */
    private int test;
    /* This is always null! */
    private LayoutObject element;
}
```

The base class looks a follows:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TrafficLayoutObject.class, name = "traffic"),
})
public abstract class LayoutObject {
    public abstract String getId();
}
```

where I use the **@JsonTypeInfo** and the **@JsonSubTypes** annotations as suggested in some tutorials.

An implementation of this class is this one:

```java
@ConstructorBinding
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TrafficLayoutObject extends LayoutObject {
    private String id;
    private String district;
}
```

which essentially adds an additional district field.

The problem now is that whenever I startup my application the **elements** field if declared as LayoutObject is null. However, when using the specific type (e.g. TrafficLayoutObject) the field is filled properly by spring.

Another interesting thing is that Jackson seems to handle this correctly because when deserializing the layout object from the config, everything is filled correctly.

What am I missing? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The configuration properties don't work with neither json (only properties or YAML) nor does it use Jackson for binding/mapping so adding those annotation will not do anything for the binding from Spring BOot (only when mapping an incoming request).

Comment: Ah ok thanks, 

Is there a way to achieve this, or does not work at all?

Comment: The configuration needs the actual type and not a base class or interface else it simply doesn't know what to instantiate.

Comment: I see, thanks for the quick response.